# What year was the song Rafaga by Joaquín Turina song written?

Tags: classical-music

Can anyone tell me what year the song Rafaga by Joaquín Turina  was originally written. I think it was originally a piano song by the transcribed to guitar in the 1930's by Andres Segovia. Can anyone tell me what year it was originally written.[This is the song on guitar.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FD5oSYykwmM)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ráfaga was composed in 1929. It WAS originally composed for guitar. Segovia just arranged and edited it.

Source: http://www.joaquinturina.com/opus53.html